Identifying eggs on my window
I live at the western tip of Britanny, France, near the town of Brest.
I noticed a strange spot on my window, inside the house, which I hypothetised was eggs of some unknown organism. Sadly, I have no better photo equipment than my phone, no tripod, nothing, so that is the best photograph I was able to make, as it was very hard to be steady and focus both.

The maximum length is around 12mm. The legs are laid flat in one layer.
A publishing amateur entomologist told me it was probably not an insect. Though it is not his domain, he is somewhat dubious about arthropods in general.
That's the extant of my research, apart from googling "ponte + keyword", "ponte" being the scientific french word both for the act of laying eggs, and for the resulting total items (i.e. the picture represents some 50 eggs and one "ponte"). I tried insects, arthropods, snails, ...
As for googling it in english, I am not aware of an english language word equivalent to the french word.
That's gonna me my first question, what keywords would lead me in the right direction.
My second question is obvious : does someone have any idea about this ? :D
The eggs matured into something looking like fish larva : a big black spot and a larval tail. Then died.
I managed to take a better picture of the "larval stage" :

Finally, thanks to a binocular, but still a phone, sadly, a picture of the "larva" :

Thanks for your interest, best regards :)

I agree they look like eggs, I would assume eggs of an insect, surprised by your friend rejecting that possibility. I think it's going to be difficult to narrow it down since so many different species might lay eggs in a similar fashion, I'd assume your best bet would be if you spot any adults indoors. Sometimes people on this site surprise me, though :)

Not an answer for you, but moths in the dark are known for laying eggs on a nice cool and flat surface.

He is the world specialist of family Tessaratomidae, so I tend to trust him, but indeed you are right that trust and science often don't mix well.

@pouzzler An amateur and also world specialist? Seems contradictory.

A professional is paid. An amateur is not. Amateurism is a different sense of the same word.
